# iOS, are "swipe to view next image" and "tap to hide ui" default functionalities?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, photo-gallery

I noticed that quite a few applications that allow you to view images have a couple default behaviors:

1. You can pinch do zoom, rotate and swipe to show the previous and next images
2. You can tap to hide the rest of the UI, and the UI is semi transparent

Since those behaviors are exactly the same on Apple's and Third Party (I.E.: Dropbox) applications, I was wondering if it is some sort of default controller provided by Apple (like UIImagePicker to take pictures).

If YES, which how can I use that controller?
if NO, any suggestions on how I can implement it?

Comment: I don't see why this question has been closed as off topic. It falls under the FAQ guideline "a specific programming problem", and it has a clear answer: either a "NO", followed by examples of how to implement it, or a "YES", followed by the specific code needed to use the functionality I asked about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, although you will see this implemented in a lot of apps, and it feel consistent, it is not something out of the box.

Swipe to next image is in fact a scroll view with images inside, using the scroll view delegate to "snap" to an image as the user moved from left to right.

Tap to show/hide UI is also just a `UITapGestureRecognizer` set up to animate show/hide the controls.

Answer (score 3):

No there is no such deafault controller, as long as I know.
You can though implement such behaviors with a few lines of Objective-C and cocoa-touch.

Start by use [UIGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIGestureRecognizer) and adding the appropriate recognizer to your UIViewController